# Refactor conversion of nested dictionary into triangular matrix in CSV file

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have the following piece of CSV file:

```
A,B,0.5
A,C,0.4
A,D,0.2
B,C,0.7
B,D,0.6
C,D,0.9
```

The task is to transform the file into a matrix format as follows (I inserted spaces for readability):

```
 ,A  ,B  ,C  ,D
B,0.5,   ,   ,
C,0.4,0.7,   ,
D,0.2,0.6,0.9,
```

The matrix can be either upper or lower triangular. I know there is a super easy way of doing this using Pandas, but I want this program to rely on the Python standard library only (because of environment issues I don't have control of).

Here is the code I developed so far:

```py
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict

# reading of CLI arguments to args.path omitted for brevity

# Part 1
with open(args.path, 'r') as infile:
    matrix = defaultdict(dict)
    for line in reader(infile):
        matrix[line[0]][line[1]] = float(line[2])

# Part 2
cols = list(matrix)
rows = set()
for col in cols:
    for j in matrix[col]:
        rows.add(j)
rows = sorted(list(rows), key=(lambda x: len(matrix[x].keys())), reverse=True)

# Part 3
print(',' + ','.join(cols))
for row in rows:
    curr_row = []
    for col in cols:
        if row in matrix[col]:
            curr_row.append(str(matrix[col][row]))
        else:
            curr_row.append('')
    curr_row = ','.join(curr_row)
    print(f'{row},{curr_row}')
```

It spits the following output:

```
,A,B,C
B,0.5,,
C,0.4,0.7,
D,0.2,0.6,0.9
```

Although it does what I want, I think `# Part 2` is a mess and `# Part 3` can be improved. I'd like to refactor the code so that it is more readable and performant (if possible). Do you know some Python tricks I can use to improve this code? Keep in mind that I need a solution using the standard library only.

Better yet would be the an output with the following format, but this is not the objective of this post. Nevertheless, suggestions are very welcome.

```
[   A    B    C    D   ]
[B] 0.5
[C] 0.4 0.7
[D] 0.2 0.6 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a more readable solution, although not the best in terms of performance (it requires O(n^2) of time and space..). I think it will suffice for my needs, but if anyone knows a better solution, please do share.

```py
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict

# reading of CLI arguments to args.path omitted for brevity

with open(args.path, 'r') as infile:
    matrix = defaultdict(dict)
    for line in reader(infile):
        matrix[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2]
        matrix[line[1]][line[0]] = line[2]

labels = sorted(matrix)
print(',' + ','.join(labels))
for row in labels:
    curr_row = []
    repeated = False
    for col in labels:
        if row in matrix[col] and not repeated:
            curr_row.append(matrix[col][row])
        else:
            curr_row.append('')
            repeated = True
    curr_row = ','.join(curr_row)
    print(row, curr_row, sep=',')
```